# What module might make all my links redirect the current window with target="_blank"?

Tags: 6

I'm at a loss. None of my own JS is doing it. When I set a link to target="_blank" it opens a new window to that location, but also redirects the original window. Does anyone have a clue what module may be involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem before and it was because of Google analytics module. This link may help you http://drupal.org/node/1091932

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how long this woulda taken me to track down by trial and error.